# IHttpClientFactory, SetBearerToken(), AddHttpClient<>, and "You're using HttpClient wrong"

Tags: httpclient, httpclientfactory

I'm sure we've all read this article that made waves back in 2016: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

For those who haven't, in summary (emphasis mine):

> Instead of creating a new instance of `HttpClient` for each execution **you should share a single instance of HttpClient for the entire lifetime of the application**.

Now, consider an ASP.NET Core application that consumes other web-services by using a `HttpClient`. Its usage of `HttpClient` falls into two general situations:

1. An outgoing request that is unauthenticated or uses the website's own credentials - in which case a single `HttpClient` really can be shared by all parts of the program.
2. An outgoing request made on behalf of one of the website's current visitors - or a request that's otherwise using request-specific credentials.

   - While a single `HttpClient` instance *can* be used, you must be careful not to mutate its state, for example, by setting `DefaultRequestHeaders` (e.g. by using the `SetBearerToken` extension method).

Practically all of the guidance for using `HttpClient` in ASP.NET Core says to:

- Use Typed Clients (POCOs that accept a `HttpClient` instance as a constructor parameter, and any other DI services).
- Register these Typed Clients using `services.AddHttpClient<TClient>()`.

  - This will register `TClient` as a **transient** instance.
  - This will register `ITypedHttpClientFactory<TClient>` as a **transient** instance.
  - This will register `IHttpClientFactory` as a **singleton**
  - This will register `IHttpMessageHandlerFactory` as a **singleton**

With that now discussed, I'll bring your attention towards a contradiction:

- The famous blog article - and now Microsoft's own documentation - says the `HttpClient` instances must be long-life'd.
- ASP.NET Core's `HttpClient` DI system really makes sure that `HttpClient` instances are short-life'd.

However, might this be okay *if* the blog article should really be talking about the underlying `HttpMessageHandler` (which is the *real* HttpClient implementation which is simply wrapped by the thin shell `class HttpClient`) - instead of the outer `class HttpClient`?

Confounding things, people report problems with using long-life'd `HttpClient` instances too and introduce other workarounds which all involve the `static class ServicePointManager` which makes me uncomfortable:

- https://itnext.io/reusing-httpclient-didnt-solve-all-my-problems-142a32a5b4d8

  - The author suggests tweaking `ServicePointManager` during application startup.
  - ...including disabling Nagle's algorithm - which I think is probably a very bad idea.
- http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html

  - The author suggests using `ConnectionLeaseTimeout`
  - ...but you need to call `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint()` for every URI you call! That doesn't seem right to me.

My questions:

- Are `HttpClient` instances *really* meant to be long-life'd or short-life'd?
- Or is it just the `HttpMessageHandler` instances that need to be long-life'd?
- If `HttpClient` or `HttpMessageHandler` instances are meant to be long-life'd:

  - How do I *correctly* address the `ServicePointManager` issues brought up in both linked blog posts?
  - Do I absolutely have to avoid using `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` and instead explicitly set the `Authorization` (Cookies or Credentials) headers on each `HttpRequestMessage`? Is there another way which has less hassle?
  - Could I add those headers using my own `DelegatingHandler`? What should be the DI registration of this proposed handler then?
- If `HttpClient` instance (but not `HttpMessageHandler` instances) are meant to be short-life'd:

  - ...then it's okay to use `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` (and `SetBearerToken()`)?
  - What is the lifetime policy of `HttpMessageHandler` instances then?
  - Can I still use `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` (and `SetBearerToken()`)?
- If `HttpClient` instance **and** `HttpMessageHandler` instances are meant to be short-life'd:

  - What about the issues mentioned in the original 2016 blog posting?

    - Does `IHttpClientFactory` do *anything* to mitigate those problems?

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem is with socket connections. `new HttpClient()` makes a new port for every request and leaves them open in the TIME_WAIT status:
[image]

This isn't the right state for them to sit in, and it takes up a socket without being reused. When the server runs out of sockets, .net throws a `SocketException` because it can't make a connection without an open socket. This is also called port exhaustion because the port runs out of sockets.

IHttpClientFactory keeps ports in the ESTABLISHED status, reuses them if another request comes in, and if no request comes in for 4 minutes, it closes them.
[image]

Your questions are all ultimately about HTTP and socket connections, but you're using .net classes to describe it. IHttpClientFactory manages the tcp socket connections with a pool of HttpClientHandlers so you don't have to. The answer to the rest of your questions are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Handlers will be reused by the factory when it needs to create new HttpClients. You can still set dynamic values like the bearer token through your own implementation, e.g. write your own `Get<T>` method that takes in a `string bearerToken` and then sets the Authorization header so you can keep that code in one place.

> ... I'll bring your attention towards a contradiction:
>
> ```
> The famous blog article - and now Microsoft's own documentation - says the HttpClient instances must be long-life'd.
> ASP.NET Core's HttpClient DI system really makes sure that HttpClient instances are short-life'd.
> ```

Where do you see Microsoft's documentation about IHttpClientFactory that says httpclients need to live long? Through the factory, they're scoped in DI, which means they're disposed at the end of the request. That's why it's safe to reuse the handler, but modify the client at runtime.